# Gulp and Node opens in different ports

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, gulp

I am trying to figure out how to serve my files through Gulp without interfering in the node processes.

I am running node with nodemon so I have to do: `nodemon server.js` and then it starts running, I have to go to my browser and type by myself: `localhost:3000` in order to see my page running.

This is part of my server.js file

```
var express = require('express');
mongoose.connect('localhost'); // LOCAL ENV

var app = express();

app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
  console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

I have a MongoDB waiting for connections.

Now in my gulp file I have this:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var csso = require('gulp-csso');
var ngAnnotate = require('gulp-ng-annotate');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var plumber = require('gulp-plumber');
var browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();

var templateCache = require('gulp-angular-templatecache');

// Compile sass into CSS & auto-inject into browsers
gulp.task('sass', function() {
  gulp.src('public/stylesheets/style.scss')
    .pipe(plumber())
    .pipe(sass())
    .pipe(csso())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('public/stylesheets'))
    .pipe(browserSync.stream());
});

gulp.task('compress', function() {
  gulp.src([
    'public/vendor/angular.js',
    'public/vendor/*.js',
    'public/app.js',
    'public/services/*.js',
    'public/controllers/*.js',
    'public/filters/*.js',
    'public/directives/*.js'
  ])
    .pipe(concat('app.min.js'))
    .pipe(ngAnnotate())
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('public'));
});

gulp.task('templates', function() {
  gulp.src('public/views/**/*.html')
    .pipe(templateCache({ root: 'views', module: 'MyApp' }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('public'));
});

gulp.task('watch', function() {
  var reload = browserSync.reload;
  gulp.watch('public/stylesheets/*.scss', ['sass']).on('change', reload);
  gulp.watch(['public/index.html', 'public/views/**/*.html'], ['templates']).on('change', reload);
  gulp.watch(['public/app.js', 'public/**/*.js',
              '!public/app.min.js', '!public/templates.js',
              '!public/vendor'], ['compress']).on('change', reload);
});

// Static Server + watching scss/html files
gulp.task('serve', ['sass'], function() {
  browserSync.init({
      server: "./public",
      port: 3000 // THIS OPENS ON 3001 BECAUSE NODE HAS THAT PORT BUSY
  });
});

gulp.task('default', ['sass', 'compress', 'templates', 'serve', 'watch']);
```

That is my `Gulpfile.js`, when I run `$ gulp` it opens in `localhost:3001` because Node has the port `3000` busy already.

I am doing this because I want Gulp to manage changes on my files and then reloads the browsers in case there is new code. And it is doing it, every time there is a change, it restarts on the port `3001` but the problem is that I can't see anything coming from the DB in the page. And if I change to `localhost:3000` I can see everything coming from the DB but I can't do the page to reload in case there are changes in the files.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You've set up two local servers;  one via node, directly, and the other with gulp/browsersync. Since you want the browsersync.reload functionality, you should just focus on that one, and not bother spinning up the node server.

Comment: @Bosworth99 but if I don't run the node server, then I can not get anything from the DB.

Comment: @Bosworth99, if I run both at the same time, I get an error about the port 3000 busy. And if I run the node server first, then the gulp server opens in port 3001, and mongo and node, are waiting the front end to be connected to the port 3000 to receive requests.

Comment: @TheUnnamed Did you find a solution for this? I am stuck on the same problem!